# Filling an array with all combinations of formula N^R

Tags: java, arrays, combinations, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

For a homework question i need to fill an array with all combinations of the formula `N^R`. The variable `R` is constant and is `6`. The variable `N` is not constant and let's say it's `2`. So `2^6 = 64`. Now what i need is an array with all the combinations (in this case `64`). I found a website which does exactly what i need and the output in this case should be:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I have tried realising this with for loops, but without succes.

I don't want the full code of an algorithm that makes this possible, but 
I want to be helped on my way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a combination in this context?

Comment: So you just want to print all the numbers in binary from `0` to `2^N`? Do they have to be in that specific format you've posted?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson this for example: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0] is a combination in this context.

Comment: @Lino Yes in that specific format :s

Comment: I can see that from your question but what is such a combination? What if N is 3?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson In this case if N = 2 the numbers 0 and 1 are used. If N = 3 then the numbers 0, 1 and 2 needs to be used. Sorry i'm not good at explaining, i hope you know what i try to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with this solution, which is a bit clumsy but should probably work for your case, the comments should explain everything:

```
public static void printCombinations(int R, int N) {
    // calculate the combinations
    String[][] combinations = calculateCombinations(R, N);
    // iterate over all
    for (int i = 0; i < combinations.length; i++) {
        // prints the commas at the end
        if (i != 0) {
            System.out.println(',');
        }
        // print to std out
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(combinations[i]));
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static String[][] calculateCombinations(int R, int N) {
    // calculate our limit
    int limit = (int) StrictMath.pow(N, R);
    // create the result array
    String[][] result = new String[limit][R];
    // iterate over all possibilities
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        // convert to base
        String base = Long.toString(i, N);
        // holds our temporary value
        StringBuilder intermediate = new StringBuilder(R);
        // pad the value from the start with zeroes if needed
        for (int sub = R - base.length(); sub > 0; sub--) {
            intermediate.append('0');
        }
        // append our number
        intermediate.append(base);

        // append to result
        result[i] = intermediate.toString().split("");
    }
    // return the result
    return result;
}
```

And can then be called like this to pretty print it out:

```
printCombinations(6, 2);
```

Or to get it as a result:

```
String[][] result = calculateCombinations(6, 2);
```

## [Running Demo](https://ideone.com/fARIXw)

Comment: Do you know by any chance how you can save a combination like [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] in  a array with this code? And everytime there is another combination the array replaces the old combination with the new combination like [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]?

Comment: @Gerrit You mean that all the combinations should be saved into an array, rather than printed out?

Comment: Yes that's what i need, sorry for not mentioning that.